# #1093 - Table 'filtros' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

Tags: mysql

I know this is a common asked question, however I do not find other way to solve this.

UPDATE filtros

SET ProvActual=1876

WHERE **Serial=(SELECT Serial FROM filtros WHERE ID=3 LIMIT 1)** AND ProvActual != 1876

LIMIT 2

I want to change 2 rows as max, which Serial is the same that the Serial from a sample ID. How can I write that? I think JOIN isn't applicable here since I'm using data from two differents rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a inner join on subselect

this should be the same without limit in  update

```
    UPDATE filtros f 
    INNER JOIN ( 
    select serial from filtros f2
    INNER JOIN 

    (
        SELECT Serial FROM filtros WHERE ID=3 LIMIT 1

    ) t f2.serial = t.serial 
    WHERE ProvActual != 1876 
    LIMIT 2 ) t2 on f.serial = t2.serial
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However the LIMIT produces #1221 error. Would be another way to say it?